# Bottom Navigation Activity when selected error occured

Tags: java, android, android-studio, duplicates, bottomnavigationview

i am beginner and learning android studio.
today i opened a new project in android studio and selected bottom navigation activity.
i haven't code any thing i just want to run this app but error occurs.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update all dependencies to the latest version to solve the error. Check below dependencies also try to have kotlin version:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Most likely, one of your dependencies uses the kotlin version of the viewmodel library whereas your code uses the java version.

Comment: not solved brother same error no solution on internet